# Bosonization and supersymmetry

Tags: condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, supersymmetry, bosonization

In 2D (time + space) there is no notion of statistic. So particles can be described in terms of bosonic and fermionic fields.

Well-known example is [Thirring/Sine-Gordon duality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271262/mathematical-content-of-thirring-sine-gordon-duality). There are also some examples: [$\phi^4$ theory kinks as fermions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261283/)

1. **Are some examples of application of bosonization in supersymmetry?**
2. Is it possible to describe some **SUSY theory only in terms of bosonic  fields**?
3. What is then meaning of SUSY transformations, realized in terms of bosons?

Comment: Tricky question. If you are pining for a SUSY theory whose bosons are Fermionized to yield a clean fermionic theory, tough luck. However, there is a tandem mutation of fermions and bosons, [*symphysis*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13270824_Canonical_non-Abelian_dual_transformations_in_supersymmetric_field_theories), under nonabelian duality transformations, [Canonical non-Abelian dual transformations in supersymmetric field theories, T Curtright & C Zachos, 1995, *PhysRev* **D52** R573(R)](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.52.R573) ...

Comment: ...which maps Noether currents to topological/nonlocal currents, as in [bosonization](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222491864_Supersymmetry_and_the_Nonlocal_Yangian_Deformation_Symmetry).

Comment: @CosmasZachos, thank you! But unfortunately I don't understand how your comment related to my question.. Is some known examples of such fermionic description of SUSY theory?

Comment: As I said, I don't know of an explicit one. But bosonization is a duality, and there are non-abelian dualities mixing everything up in supersymmetric theories, preserving supersymmetry.